# Typing indicator for bot framework in C#

Tags: botframework

I have a bot in Bot framework. Once user responds to the bot and bot is processing it, I want to show the typing indicator to the user in the meanwhile.

It is possible in Nodejs here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-typing-indicator

But how can I implement it in C#?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to send an activity of type `Typing`.

You can do it like that:

```
// Send "typing" information
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply();
reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
reply.Text = null;
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
await connector.Conversations.ReplyToActivityAsync(reply);
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also create the message using `context.MakeMessage` if you need to instantly respond in `MessageReceivedAsync` of a dialog.

```
var typingMsg = context.MakeMessage();
typingMsg.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
typingMsg.Text = null;
await context.PostAsync(typingMsg);
```

The typing indicator is replaced by the next message sent (at least in the Bot Framework emulator). This doesn't seem to work in Slack.

Answer (score 1):

For showing typing indicator while bot is processing just add in OnTurnAsync function before await base.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken); :

```
await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(new Activity { Type = ActivityTypes.Typing }, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: This worked well in my `OnMessageActivityAsync` activity handler method. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach to [send a typing indicator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=lg) with a bot framework in C#, JavaScript, or Python.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this:

```
var reply = activity.CreateReply();
reply.Text = null;
reply.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;

await context.PostAsync(reply);
```

Answer (score -1):

If V4, following lines of code can help. Keep this code at such a place so that it gets executed everytime during the dialogue flow.

```
        IMessageActivity reply1 = innerDc.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
        reply1.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
        reply1.Text = null;
        await innerDc.Context.SendActivityAsync( reply1, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
```