# Bot Framework .Net. Add typing indicator on Bot

Tags: c#, .net, botframework

I want to add a typing indicator before the bot reply to the user on the WaterfallStepContext. Is it possible?

[image]

Comment: To get the typing indicator, you need to [send an activity of type `Typing`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889917/typing-indicator-for-bot-framework-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Any idea how to implement it on WaterFallStepContext? @stuartd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can send a "Typing" Activity from a WaterfallStepContext by

1. Creating a reply from the context
2. Setting the type to ActivityTypes.Typing
3. Then sending it from the context

```
    Activity TypingActivity = stepContext.Context.Activity.CreateReply();
    TypingActivity.Type = ActivityTypes.Typing;
    await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync(TypingActivity);
```

Comment: Great! It worked man. Thanks. I added a delay so it will not fade right away.