# How to show typing indicator when user is signing in

Tags: c#, .net-core, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I have a bot created with bot-framework v4, also I implemented enhanced authentication for single sign-on. The only issue is that when the user clicks the "Authenticate/Sign in" button it takes between 10 and 15 seconds to get signed in, and sometimes users click the button again which generates an error message. Is it possible to add a typing indicator or a message as soon as users click the button? I was checking AuthPrompt but I don't see any option to implement this.
Thanks in advance!

Edit

This is the code I'm using:

AuthDialog.cs

```
    public AuthDialog(IBotServices services, IConfiguration configuration, IBotTelemetryClient telemetryClient, UserState userState, ConversationState conversationState)
    {
        AddDialog(new WaterfallDialog(InitialDialog)
            .AddStep(Authenticate)
            .AddStep(ConfirmLogin));

        AddDialog(new OAuthPrompt(
            nameof(OAuthPrompt),
            new OAuthPromptSettings
            {
                ConnectionName = configuration["ConnectionName"],
                Text = "Please sign in.",
                Title = "Get Started",
                Timeout = 300000, // User has 5 minutes to login                  
            }));

        _userState = userState;

        this.TelemetryClient = telemetryClient;

        InitialDialogId = InitialDialog;
    }

    private async Task<DialogTurnResult> Authenticate(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await stepContext.BeginDialogAsync(nameof(OAuthPrompt), null, cancellationToken);
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-send-messages

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typing indicator for bot framework in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47889917/typing-indicator-for-bot-framework-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I know about the Typing activity and I have added the [Typing Middleware](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/blob/main/libraries/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/ShowTypingMiddleware.cs) but It's not being displayed when the user clicks the "Authenticate" button.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the code to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

So, to handle the original problem you mentioned in the question about, user clicking the sign in button again, You can handle that on Click of the sign in button itself by disabling the sign in button till you get a token response for the sign in activity. Based on the response(success / failure), you can choose to enable the button again or move to the next step instead of only relying on typing indicator.